# Issue With GROUP BY In Query

Tags: oracle, plsql

First of all, thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer!

I'm fairly new to Oracle, so I apologize if this question is stupid...

I'm having an issue getting a query to run properly, and the issue is with the GROUP BY clause in the query.

When running the query, I get the error stating that it's not a GROUP BY statement?? Not really sure what that means.

Here is the query:

```
with SUB_GRP_LVL_1 as
(
        select sg.HCC_ID,sge.SUB_GROUP_NAME 
        from XXXX_ODS.GROUP_T g
        Join XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP sg
            on g.GROUP_KEY=sg.GROUP_KEY
            and g.HCC_ID NOT IN('A0002','A0003','A0004','A0005','A0021','A0022','A0041','A0042','A0081','A0121','A0061')
            and sg.REC_SRC_CD='HS1'
            and sg.LEVEL_NBR=1
        join XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP_EFF sge
            on sge.SUB_GROUP_KEY=sg.SUB_GROUP_KEY
            ---and sge.CURRENT_INDC=1
            and sge.ACTIVE_INDC=1
)
,    

SUB_GRP_LVL_2 as
(
        select sg.HCC_ID,sge.SUB_GROUP_NAME 
        from XXXX_ODS.GROUP_T g
        Join XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP sg
            on g.GROUP_KEY=sg.GROUP_KEY
            and g.HCC_ID NOT IN('A0002','A0003','A0004','A0005','A0021','A0022','A0041','A0042','A0081','A0121','A0061')
            and sg.REC_SRC_CD='HS1'
            and sg.LEVEL_NBR=2
        join XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP_EFF sge
            on sge.SUB_GROUP_KEY=sg.SUB_GROUP_KEY
            and sge.ACTIVE_INDC=1
)
,

GRP_BEN_PL_ID as
(
        select sg.SUB_GROUP_KEY,bpe.HCC_BENEFIT_PLAN_ID , sgbp.EFFECTIVE_DT, sgbp.EXPIRATION_DT, pe.FUNDING_TYPE, pe.HCC_PROD_ID, pe.STATE_CD, pe.SUB_COMPANY
        from XXXX_ODS.GROUP_T g
        Join XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP sg
            on g.GROUP_KEY=sg.GROUP_KEY
            and g.HCC_ID NOT IN('A0002','A0003','A0004','A0005','A0021','A0022','A0041','A0042','A0081','A0121','A0061')
            and g.REC_SRC_CD='HS1'
        JOIN XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP_BENEFIT_PLAN sgbp
            on sg.SUB_GROUP_KEY=sgbp.SUB_GROUP_KEY
            ---and sgbp.CURRENT_INDC=1
            and sgbp.ACTIVE_INDC=1
        join XXXX_ODS.BENEFIT_PLAN_EFF bpe 
            on sgbp.BENEFIT_PLAN_KEY = bpe.BENEFIT_PLAN_KEY
            and bpe.ACTIVE_INDC=1
        join XXXX_ods.product_eff pe
            on bpe.PRODUCT_KEY=pe.product_key
            and pe.ACTIVE_INDC=1
)

select 
        BLK_1.SUB_GROUP_KEY,ACCT_NBR AS GROUPID,
        SUB_GRP_ID, 
        DIVISION_ID 
        ,GRP_BEN_PL_ID.HCC_BENEFIT_PLAN_ID
        ,INVOICE_NBR
        ,'CMD' BUSTYPE, 
        GRP_BEN_PL_ID.FUNDING_TYPE AS BUSSUBTYPE,
        GRP_BEN_PL_ID.HCC_PROD_ID AS PROCODE,
        '' AS PREMIUMTYPE, 
        INV.CURRENT_INVOICED_AMT AS PREMIUMBILLED, 
        INV.CURRENT_INVOICED_AMT AS PREMIUMDUEDATE, 
        '' AS PREMIUMPAID, 
        '' AS PREMIUMAPPLYDATE, 
        COUNT(invl.INVOICE_LINE_KEY) AS CONTRACTSXXXXL, 
        '' AS MEMBERSXXXXL
        --ACCOUNT_TYPE
        ,DECODE (UPPER(GRP_BEN_PL_ID.STATE_CD),'NEBRASKA','NE','IOWA','IA') STATE, 
        GRP_BEN_PL_ID.SUB_COMPANY LGL_ENTITY,
        LEVEL_NBR 
from
        (
                select 
                    g.GROUP_KEY, sg.SUB_GROUP_KEY, g.HCC_ID ACCT_NBR,ge.GROUP_NAME ACCT_NAME,substr(sg.HCC_ID, 1,instr(sg.hcc_id,'-',1,2)-1) SUB_GRP_ID,sg.HCC_ID DIVISION_ID,ce.FIRST_EFFECTIVE_DT,
                add_months(
                decode(ce.EFFECTIVE_DT,TO_DATE('01/01/1800','MM/DD/YYYY'),ce.FIRST_EFFECTIVE_DT,ce.EFFECTIVE_DT),ce.RENEWAL_INTERVAL) RENVL_DT, ce.ACCOUNT_TYPE
                , sg.LEVEL_NBR
                from 
                    XXXX_ODS.CUSTOMER_EFF ce
                join XXXX_ODS.GROUP_T g
                    on g.CUSTOMER_KEY=ce.CUSTOMER_KEY
                Join XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP sg
                    on g.GROUP_KEY=sg.GROUP_KEY
                    and g.HCC_ID NOT IN('A0002','A0003','A0004','A0005','A0021','A0022','A0041','A0042','A0081','A0121','A0061')
                    and g.REC_SRC_CD='HS1'
                    and sg.LEVEL_NBR=2
                    and g.HCC_ID not like 'TEST%'
                join XXXX_ODS.GROUP_EFF ge
                    on ge.GROUP_KEY = g.GROUP_KEY
                    and ge.CURRENT_INDC=1
                union  
                select 
                gp.GROUP_KEY,
                    sgp.SUB_GROUP_KEY, gp.HCC_ID ACCT,gep.GROUP_NAME, sgp.HCC_ID SUB_GRP, NULL DIVISION,cep.FIRST_EFFECTIVE_DT,
                    add_months(decode(cep.EFFECTIVE_DT,TO_DATE('01/01/1800','MM/DD/YYYY'),cep.FIRST_EFFECTIVE_DT,cep.EFFECTIVE_DT),cep.RENEWAL_INTERVAL) RENVL_DT,
                    cep.ACCOUNT_TYPE, sgp.LEVEL_NBR
                from 
                    XXXX_ODS.CUSTOMER_EFF cep
                join XXXX_ODS.GROUP_T gp
                    on gp.CUSTOMER_KEY=cep.CUSTOMER_KEY
                Join XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP sgp
                    on gp.GROUP_KEY=sgp.GROUP_KEY
                    and gp.HCC_ID NOT IN('A0002','A0003','A0004','A0005','A0021','A0022','A0041','A0042','A0081','A0121','A0061')
                    and gp.REC_SRC_CD='HS1'
                    and sgp.LEVEL_NBR=1
                    and gp.HCC_ID not like 'TEST%'
                    join XXXX_ODS.GROUP_EFF gep
                    on gep.GROUP_KEY = gp.GROUP_KEY
                    and gep.CURRENT_INDC=1
                    and not exists
                                    (
                                            select 'X'
                                            from 
                                                XXXX_ODS.GROUP_T gi
                                            Join XXXX_ODS.SUB_GROUP sgi
                                                on gi.GROUP_KEY=sgi.GROUP_KEY
                                                and gi.HCC_ID NOT IN('A0002','A0003','A0004','A0005','A0021','A0022','A0041','A0042','A0081','A0121','A0061')
                                                and gi.REC_SRC_CD='HS1'
                                                and sgi.LEVEL_NBR=2
                                                and gi.HCC_ID not like 'TEST%'
                                            where 
                                                gp.HCC_ID=gi.HCC_ID 
                                                and sgp.HCC_ID=substr(sgi.HCC_ID, 1,instr(sgi.hcc_id,'-',1,2)-1)
                                    )
         ) BLK_1
        join SUB_GRP_LVL_1 
            on SUB_GRP_LVL_1.HCC_ID=BLK_1.SUB_GRP_ID
        left join SUB_GRP_LVL_2 
            on SUB_GRP_LVL_2.HCC_ID=BLK_1.DIVISION_ID
        left join GRP_BEN_PL_ID
            on GRP_BEN_PL_ID.SUB_GROUP_KEY=BLK_1.SUB_GROUP_KEY
        LEFT Join XXXX_ODS.INVOICE inv
         on inv.BILL_TO_GROUP_KEY = BLK_1.GROUP_KEY
         LEFT JOIN XXXX_ODS.INVOICE_BILLING_CATEGORY invbc
         on invbc.INVOICE_KEY = inv.INVOICE_KEY
         LEFT JOIN XXXX_ODS.INVOICE_LINE invl
         on invl.INVOICE_BILLING_CATEGORY_KEY = invbc.INVOICE_BILLING_CATEGORY_KEY
         GROUP BY
         GRP_BEN_PL_ID.SUB_GROUP_KEY,
         ACCT_NBR, --AS GROUPID,
         SUB_GRP_ID, 
         DIVISION_ID 
        ,GRP_BEN_PL_ID.HCC_BENEFIT_PLAN_ID
        ,INVOICE_NBR
       ,BUSTYPE 
        ,GRP_BEN_PL_ID.FUNDING_TYPE,
        ,GRP_BEN_PL_ID.HCC_PROD_ID --AS PROCODE,
        ,PREMIUMTYPE
        ,INV.CURRENT_INVOICED_AMT 
        PREMIUMBILLED, 
        INV.CURRENT_INVOICED_AMT --AS PREMIUMDUEDATE, 
        ,PREMIUMPAID 
       ,PREMIUMAPPLYDATE 
        ,MEMBERSXXXXL
        ACCOUNT_TYPE
        ,STATE_CD, 
         GRP_BEN_PL_ID.SUB_COMPANY,
        ,LEVEL_NBR 
       order by ACCT_NBR,SUB_GRP_ID,LEVEL_NBR,DIVISION_ID
;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**NEW ANSWER BASED ON COMMENT**

Sorry I should have looked a bit closer I read the statement 'I get the error stating that it's not a GROUP BY statement' saw the count and made an assumption with my original answer.

With the further information provided in the comments I think the issue is actually that you are using the column alias in the group by.

When grouping you actually have to use the field names not the alias, if you have a static value (in this case '' AS MEMBERSXXXXL) you do not need to group by it SO

**incorrect select using alias in the group by**

```
select column1, column2 || column 3 as test2, '' as test, count(1) as cnt
from table
group by column1, test2, test
```

**correct select omitting static value and putting full field in the group by**

```
select column1, column2 || column 3 as test2, '' as test, count(1) as cnt
from table
group by column1, column2 || column 3
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW**
where you have a count, min, max, sum ect within your select statement you need to tell it how to group the other columns....

you have

`COUNT(invl.INVOICE_LINE_KEY) AS CONTRACTSXXXXL,`

This means you will need a group by clause on your select.

Good resource for basics of this is

https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-group-by/

Comment: I do have a GROUP BY statement, it's just not behaving properly. As I mentioned, when executing tjhe query, it errors on the GROUP BY clause. It returns an error saying MEMBERSMEDICAL: invalid identifier.  The MEMBERSMEDICAL column is in the SELECT statement, so not sure why this error is being thrown.

Comment: @Ansonee sorry misunderstood problem, I have updated my answer based on your comments